# How to hide some text on options in select2 dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I am having a products list in select2 dropdown like this.

```
<option>Product A [Barcode]</option>
<option>Product A [Barcode]</option>
<option>Product A [Barcode]</option>
<option>Product A [Barcode]</option>
```

Now 
I want to hide the barcode from the option but want the search to find the product if barcode is entered. I tried

```
<option>Product A <span style='display:none;'>[Barcode]</span></option>
```

But no success. Was not able to find answer in the documentation. Please help.

Comment: Show what you have tried before asking help.

Comment: Read the question carefully what I have tried before commenting

Comment: Where is your answer? or you mean to say question?

Answer (score 0):

Option element can't have any child elements inside, so you could move your barcode values in option's 'value" attribute. Then define select2 matcher function to search through option values.

https://select2.org/searching

```
$('#mySelect').select2({
  matcher: function(params, data) {
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') { return data; }
    // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') { return null; }

    // check for both value and text
    var searchTarget = params.term.toLowerCase();
    if (data.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTarget) > -1 || data.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTarget) > -1) {
        return $.extend({}, data, true);
    }
    //
    return null;
}
});
```

And result is something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/scarabs/canrx12k/